# Typescript design patterns to embed objects within other objects. ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

I have short example code placed on github (but it is too long to write it here). I found some workarounds that TS would not complain, but would like to get a professional help how to properly write this with TypeScript.

Also, could anyone advise what the most appropriate title might be for this case, that others could find this case easy. On the same topic, does anyone know what is the name of such a technique?

[TypeScript code example link](https://github.com/DenisTimofijuk/super_mario_snowpack_ts/blob/main/src/not%20related%20experiments/testingEnitites.ts).

```
addDepartment<T extends Departments>(Department: T) {
this.departments.push(Department);
// this[Department.name] = Department as ITdeppartment & ACCdeppartment; //Working workaround, but would like to have something smarter


/**
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ITdeppartment & ACCdeppartment'.
    Type 'Departments' is not assignable to type 'ITdeppartment & ACCdeppartment'.
      Type 'ITdeppartment' is not assignable to type 'ITdeppartment & ACCdeppartment'.
        Type 'ITdeppartment' is missing the following properties from type 'ACCdeppartment': accounts, addAccount
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ITdeppartment'.
            Type 'Departments' is not assignable to type 'ITdeppartment'.
              Property 'checkNetwork' is missing in type 'ACCdeppartment' but required in type 'ITdeppartment'. ts(2322)
 */
this[Department.name] = Department; // <= ERROR ts(2322) }
```

Result:

```
const downTown = new Office();
downTown.addDepartment<ITdeppartment>(new ITdeppartment());
```

Comment: I would rename the post to something along the lines of: "Typescript design patterns to embed objects within other objects."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`instanceof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) instead of the `name` property on `Department`, you can tell TypeScript that only the IT `Department` will ever be assigned to `it` property of the `Office` and similarly with the ACC `Department`.

A full code example would look something like this:

```
class Department {
  tasks: any[];
  constructor() {
    this.tasks = [];
  }

  addTask(task: any) {
    this.tasks.push(task);
  }
}

class ITdeppartment extends Department {
  functionName = 'Information Technology';

  checkNetwork(task: string) {
    console.log(`Checking ${task}`);
  }
}

class ACCdeppartment extends Department {
  functionName = 'Accounting';
  accounts: string[] = [];

  addAccount(acc: string) {
    this.accounts.push(acc);
  }
}

class Office {
  departments: Array<Department> = [];
  it!: ITdeppartment;
  acc!: ACCdeppartment;

  addDepartment<T extends Department>(department: T) {
    this.departments.push(department);
    if (department instanceof ITdeppartment) {
      this.it = department;
    }
    if (department instanceof ACCdeppartment) {
      this.acc = department;
    }
  }
}

const downTown = new Office();
downTown.addDepartment(new ITdeppartment());
downTown.addDepartment(new ACCdeppartment());

downTown.it.addTask('New IT Task');
downTown.it.checkNetwork('Office network');

downTown.acc.addTask('New ACC task');
downTown.acc.addAccount('Testing new account');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to accomplish wonder if this approach is going to be more optimal:

```
abstract class Department {
  tasks: any[];
  
  constructor() {
    this.tasks = [];
  }
  

  addTask(task: any) {
    this.tasks.push(task);
  }
}

class ITdepartment extends Department {
  functionName: string;
  constructor(private office: Office) {
    super();
    this.functionName = 'Information Technology';
  }

  checkNetwork(task: string):void {
    console.log(`Checking ${task} of ${this.office.name}`);
  }
}

class ACCdepartment extends Department {
  functionName: string;
  accounts: string[];
  constructor(private office: Office) {
    super();
    this.functionName = 'Accounting';
    this.accounts = [];
  }

  addAccount(acc: string):void {
    this.accounts.push(acc);
    console.log(`pushing ${acc} to ${this.office.name}`)
  }
}


class Office {

  constructor(public name:string) {}
  
}

const downTown = new Office('down town');
const itDept = new ITdepartment(downTown);
const accDept = new ACCdepartment(downTown);


itDept.addTask('New IT Task');
itDept.checkNetwork('Office network');

accDept.addTask('New ACC task');
accDept.addAccount('Testing new account');
```

In the above sample instead of passing departments into the `Office` object I'm passing `Office` object into corresponding `Department` object. This makes your `Departments` aware of the `Office` they belong to and thus apply actions/tasks with regard to the corresponding office. For instance new accounts added by the department likely belong to the specific office rather than dept itself. Just an idea anyway.